# My TTS is not working in Android Lollipop (21)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, text-to-speech, flite

I have created a TTS engine based on [Flite](https://github.com/happyalu/Flite-TTS-Engine-for-Android) for Android which works well on all versions below 21.

But when I run it in an Android Lollipop emulator, in the Text-to-Speech Settings screen, the option for reading a sample text is disabled and when I press the Settings button next to my TTS, the Settings crashes! However, the TTS works fine when used from other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of struggling, I finally found that using underscore (`_`) in locale names (like `fas-IRN-male_odj`) which was used in voice file names, confuses Android and it cannot parse language, country and variant parts out of it.

It seems Android 21 treats `_` and `-` both as separators in locale names and since it expects at most 3 parts for a locale definition (language, country and variant) falls in trouble with something that has 4 parts.